# o2 mobile broadband won't connect with a Huawei E173

Tags: 11.10, broadband

It's connected and configured via the wizard but Enable Mobile Broadband is unchecked by default and nothing happens when I click it.

When I click on the o2 mobile broadband connection itself it briefly (around half a second) connects (the icon changes) then disconnects and I get the notification disconnected from network.  The usb modem is HUAWEI E173.

I understand there have been some issues in this regard with 11.10 and just wondered if anyone else had gotten one working?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change some settings in network manager (edit connections):

- APN: m-bb.o2.co.uk
- phone number: *99#
- username: o2bb
- password:password

Once you've connected, go to mobilebroadbandaccess.o2.co.uk to register. I found I was disconnected fairly soon after my initial connection, but after reconnecting (either reboot or remove and reinsert the mobile broadband dongle) it seems to work fine.

Comment: Is this contract or PAYG settings?

Comment: Thanks Tom, those settings worked for me, but I had to deselect 'Enable Mobile Broadband' for the dongle to connect properly.